# How to make an array of vectors and matrices in Julia

Tags: matrix, julia

I don't know how to make an array of vectors and matrices in Julia. For example, how I make a list `p` such that

```
p[1]=[1;2]
p[2]=[2 3; 4 5]
```

?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an array of "Any"

```
p=Any[[1;2],[2 3; 4 5]]
```

which returns

> ```
> 2-element Array{Any,1}:
>  [1, 2]
>  [2 3; 4 5]
> ```

Comment: As a small comment - adding `Any` is crucial here, as if you omit it Julia in some cases might perform type conversion when constructing a wrapper vector. Here is an example when this happens (with omitted `Any`): `[[1.0], [1]]`.

Comment: Well, it's not crucial here, since type conversion won't happen. Also, if you just write `[[1,2], [2 3; 4 5]]` you get a tighter type bound, `Any` might be undesirable. Perhaps `Array[[1,2], [2 3; 4 5]]` or `Array{Int}[[1,2], [2 3; 4 5]]` are better options.

Comment: In this particular example it will not happen indeed, but it would in general. As @sotowa wants to mix vectors and matrices the most efficient in this case would be `Union{Vector{Int}, Matrix{Int}}[[1;2],[2 3; 4 5]]` assuming only `Vector{Int}` and `Matrix{Int}` elements would be passed.